# SQL Connection failed after deployment: "Login failed for user '' "

Tags: asp.net, sql, iis, deployment, connection-string

I'm having a problem with my ASP.NET Application after I have deployed it. Everything was working well in debug mode, however after deployment any page that attempts to connect to the DB gives this error:

Login failed for user ''.

My SQLConnection String is:

```
sdb.ConnectionString = "Data Source=< SQLServerAddress >;Initial Catalog=sdb;";
```

Originally I had

```
Integrated Security=true;
```

Appended to my connection string, however this resulted in a similar error message:

> "Login failed for user '< domain >\< computer name >$'."

I am new to IIS but have followed guides to set it up. My site is using the DefaultAppPool with its identity set to NetworkService (Although I have tried ApplicationPoolIdentity and it seems to change nothing.)

I've added the NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE account in SQL server for my database as db_owner permissions as well.

Under the Authentication settings I have Anonymous Authentication user identity set to "Application pool identity".

I have given permissions to the C:\inetpub\wwwroot folder to NETWORK SERVICE but that didn't seem to help anything either.

I'm really not sure what else to try. I can see that the problem must be with permissions or identities since everything worked well in Visual Studio debugging, but I'm not sure where the problem is post-deployment. This is my first IIS deployment and is for a project for my undergrad computer science program at university. I've been searching google for a good part of the day and tried many applicable suggestions but unfortunately nothing seems to be working, and I'm a bit unsure of what to search for now for a solution.

I'm not sure if it matters or not but I connect to my database all from codebehind, the code to connect and a bit of how I'm using it is as follows:

```
SqlDataSource sdb = new SqlDataSource();
sdb.ConnectionString = "Data Source=< SQLServerAddress >;Initial Catalog=sdb;";
sdb.SelectCommand = "SELECT someAttribute, someOtherAtt FROM SomeTable";
dropDownList.DataSource = sdb;
dropDownList.DataTextField = "someAttribute";
dropDownList.DataValueField = "someOtherAtt";
```

Comment: Does the server yo are trying to connect enable Windows Authentication? If it is an SQL Server database that does support it, you must supply a valid User ID and Password in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

you should create a specific service account for your application, an AD account for which you know password and user name and it is used only for this application, then you configure SQL Server to allow connection for this AD account and grant the proper rights, trying to only grant the minimum permissions set strictly required for your application to run correctly.

then you get back to the web server where you have deployed the application and you create an application pool which runs impersonating the AD service account you just created and finally setup your website/web application to run with that application pool.

this does the trick, good luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Sorry I'm not familiar with the term "AD Account," is this an administrator account? Do I just create it the same way I'd make a normal user account? The rest of your solution I understand and can attempt. Thanks for your time.

Comment: are you in a network with an Active Directory domain? if yes, an AD account is an active directory account you can get created by an administrator on the domain controller machine. if your network has not Active Directory domain, my answer does not help you unfortunately.

Comment: Very possible, the network we are attempting to deploy this on is the university network. I'll ask the network admin if he can set us up with an account. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Link to create sql server user and add the username and password on the connection string in the webconfig.

[Create a SQL Server Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa337562%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

in the webconfig file add the connection sting as follows

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="server=SQLServerAddress;database=sdb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: on codebehind u have to take the connection from webconfig file.